# Vertical positioning of text in table

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, positioning

I am having problem with positioning the text into the fist row of the cell in the table.I would be grateful if someone could help me sort it out.

The code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|  L{3cm} | L{3cm} | C{3cm} | R{3cm} |}

\hline

foo &

\tabitem A cell with text that wraps around\newline

\tabitem is raggedright and allows 
    manual line breaks &

\tabitem A cell with text that wraps around 

&
A cell with text that wraps around, is raggedleft and allows 
\newline
    manual line breaks \\ 
    \hline   
\end{tabular}


\end{document}


\end{document}
```

The table looks like this now:

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `p` column instead of the `m` to have the text start at the top of the cell. Also, normal `itemize` could be used after proper adjustment of parameters to suit `tabular`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,array}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}

\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin = *, itemsep=-3pt, before=\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\partopsep}, after=\vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip+\partopsep}}

\begin{tabular}{| L{3cm} | L{3cm} | C{3cm} | R{3cm} |}
\hline
foo
&
\begin{itemize}
\item A cell with text that wraps around 
\item is raggedright and allows manual line breaks 
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{itemize}
\item A cell with text that wraps around 
\end{itemize} 
&
A cell with text that wraps around, is raggedleft and allows \newline
manual line breaks \\ \hline   
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]